# Clearing stack including activities in different tasks

Tags: android, android-intent, task

I have a main activity A. There are two scenarios

1) A launches B.
    B has launchmode singleTask and is launched with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
    now I have a menu option in B which performs a delete operation and starts the activity A.

2) A launches B, which launces C it also contains the menu option to perform delet opereation.

I want A to be started with clearing the stack in both the scenarios but the activities belonging to another task still present there
I am stuck is there a way to clear the stack.

Comment: Any information about managing the stack is located at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html But `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `clearTaskOnLaunch` may be worth looking at, though they don't provide the exact functioning that you seem to desire.

Comment: thanks, but I have already gone through the documentation didn't find any solution.

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK seems to be the option I am not sure though, is there any chance of using it on API Level 8.

Comment: did u try `startActivityForResult()` in activity A and B for both the scenarios, u can also manage something using flags between these activities

Comment: nice question +1 for you

Comment: Just to be sure this is actually working like you think it is, have you set android:taskAffinity in any of these activities? Please post your manifest, as it will help.

Answer (score 1):

try using following code on delete opereation on both B and C activity

```
    Intent intent=new Intent(B.this, A.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP doesn't work in this case because I have two different tasks running in my application.

Answer (score 0):

If i talk about your second scenario then `FLAG_ACTIVITY_TOP_CLEAR`will clear the stack..

And your stack now will be only `A` instead of `A-B-C-A`.

and in second case AFAIU your problem you have only two activity A and B so if you want to restart A then after restarting A manually finish B.

Hope you got some trick.

Another thing if you have activity with `launchmode=SingleTask` then you can use flag_activity_brought_to_front.

```
That will act like
```

A-B-c  to A

Answer (score 0):

Why not finishing B and C before calling A again?

```
finish();
```

Comment: how can you call finish() of Activity B if you are in Activity A?

Answer (score 0):

My method can not meet your goal `A to be started with clearing the stack`,But when user choose `delet opereation` and start B from A again the task that include A and B will be  reset.

Use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET` to mark the task will be clear when needed when you first start activity B from A, then if user choose `delet opereation` menu item from B or C, you set a flag, so next time from A(A should be single_task launch mode in manifest), you use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED` to start B. This flag will clear B and all top of the B.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: A is running in task 1 and B and C are running in task 2. Now when I start A from either B or C, I think what happening is A leaves its actual task and become part of task 2.

Comment: You should make the launch mode of A as `singleTask` or set flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` so that next time you start A, it will go to the existed A.

Comment: I have done that but when I press back button I see either B or C present on the stack.

Comment: Try use android:launchMode="singleTask" instead of setting flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, It works for me. But The flag don't work for me though the android document said they are the same, i'm trying to find why.

Comment: B or C still in the stack though you have set the launch mode of A to singleTask in the manifest when you press back button? I'm confused.